# Right align the content in a column inside a row

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design to create a row contains two columns, I want the content in a column to be right aligned.

My code:

```
        <Row gutter={[0, 8]}>
            <Col span={15}>
                {currentProject.tags &&
                        currentProject.tags.map((tag, index) => (
                            <Tag key={index}>
                                {tag}
                            </Tag>
                        ))}
            </Col>
            <Col span={9}></Col>
        </Row>
```

I want the content inside the column with span={15} to be right aligned. I tried `style={{justifySelf: 'right'}}` , `style={{justifyContent: 'right'}}`, `style={{justifyItems: 'right'}}` they are all failed.

Does any one how to use the right CSS to align the content right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add `display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'` to your Col:

```
 <Row gutter={[0, 8]}>
        <Col span={15} style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
            {currentProject.tags &&
                    currentProject.tags.map((tag, index) => (
                        <Tag key={index}>
                            {tag}
                        </Tag>
                    ))}
        </Col>
        <Col span={9}></Col>
    </Row>
```

You can check it [here](https://ant.design/components/grid/)

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to only right-align the content in Col with span={15}?

Comment: I edit the answer, please check it :)

Comment: It works, thank you!!

Comment: Please accept the answer as the best. Thank you

Comment: May I ask one more question why when I add ```justify="end"``` on Row and all the content inside the columns doesn't align right?

Comment: I believe that this happens because the 2 columns you have (15&9) occupy the entire space of row. Make a try with two `<Col span={6}>`